# No suitable driver found for connection url (MySQL+WildFly)

Tags: java, mysql, wildfly

I faced the following problem: I need to make my web app work with the database. For this purpose, I created the database in MySQL. Connection URL for this database is the following: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab3?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC`. Also, I created the DataSource in WildFly Management console:

[image]

I tested the connection, everything is ok. But when I run the project, I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab3?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC
13:28:15,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:702)
13:28:15,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
13:28:15,524 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.lab5_ear_exploded.ear.web.war//model.Model.<init>(Model.java:13)
13:28:15,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at deployment.lab5_ear_exploded.ear.web.war//controller.NewJSFManagedBean.<init>(NewJSFManagedBean.java:17)
13:28:15,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
13:28:15,525 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
13:28:15,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
13:28:15,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
13:28:15,526 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
13:28:15,527 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP06//com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:162)
13:28:15,527 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP06//com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:76)
13:28:15,527 ERROR [stderr] (default task-1)    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP06//com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:387)
...
```

Here's the way how I am trying to connect to DB in code:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class Model {

    private Statement statement;

    public Model() {
        try {
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lab3?useUnicode=true&serverTimezone=UTC", "root", "12345");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM customer");
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString("address"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

So, maybe someone knows what's the problem? I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance!

**UPD**

Here's what is inside my deployment artifact:

[image]

Comment: do you use gradle or maven ? or you trying to create a JNDI inside wild fly ?

Comment: @DickensAS, I have maven jsf project

Comment: I have provided the answer for both and manual download whichever you want to use , you can do

Answer (score 0):

If you use Gradle then you need to add the dependency

```
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.19'
```

If you use Maven then you need to add the dependency

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>mysql</groupId>
      <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
      <version>8.0.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

If you want to directly download the JAR and put inside WEB-INF\lib then download from here

```
    https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.19/mysql-connector-java-8.0.19.jar
```

If you are using JNDI then your code not correct, you need to copy this war into your WilDFly lib directory and only use JNDI code

Reference:  https://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/jndi-resources-howto.html

Comment: I had Maven dependency, but it didn't work. Then I downloaded jar file, added it as the library, but it also didn't fix the issue

Comment: you are mixing up JNDI and direct JDBC, lab3 is a JNDI, your code is incorrect

Comment: So, now I added the library again with Maven, but the issue is still the same:

Comment: delete the data source and try, as I told you are mixing up JNDI and direct JDBC, and use a zip software and see inside this file `lab5_ear_exploded` what is inside it, you can use 7Zip, you can even manually add the jar inside it and re-deploy and testing purpose

Comment: I deleted all data sources in console, created new, but still have the same issue

Comment: where is the wildfly installed, can you copy paste the mysql jar into the lib folder

Comment: Do you mean this folder: `\standalone\lib` ?

Comment: you can try that, but I am still thinking that you are mixing up things, WildFly JDNI is different, and your code is completely irrelevant, `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql` is only for direct JDBC

Comment: So, as I understand, connection url should be another?

Comment: yes, it should be JNDI url please refer the docs for adding a JNDI URL in web.xml and context.xml which will help you

Comment: I looked through several tutorials (for example this: https://www.journaldev.com/7068/jsf-database-example-mysql-jdbc) and as I understand the use almost the same URL as I have, but it works in their project

Comment: they are using WAR, but you are using EAR, EAR has two lib folder, one at the WAR side, another at the EJB side, which is used for the jar files, see this documentation https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch01s04s02.html